# Ignore folders or files deployed on server using web deploy package

Tags: iis, web-deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

We have some configuration files in our web application, e.g. settings.js that are specific to a given environment and created during the initial setup of the web page. We are building a web package using visual studio 2015 and deploy the package using the generated cmd file (web deploy 3.5).

I have tried many suggested solutions to have the file not being updated or removed when deploying a new version of the web package but nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? Basically, the settings.js file on the server should just be ignored and not touched at all by the upgrade.
I thought that would be something very basic and that web deploy could handle very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the file when packaging via MSBuild:

```
 <ItemGroup> 
    <DeploymentFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/_deployment/**" />
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="@(DeploymentFiles)"> 
        <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget> 
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles> 
 </ItemGroup>
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/05/19/extending-the-webdeploy-manifest/

And also want to not delete existing files on the site that aren't in the package using the following MSDeploy flag:

```
-enableRule:DoNotDelete
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/01/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-keep-existing-files-during-deployment/